# Camel:Spring-DSL:Multicats 'timeout' attribute from properties

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-dsl

I want to set timeout attribute in multicast tag from a external property file. 
I can use properties without issue with *{{property.name}}* syntax in uri,etc definitions.
However below usage seems like not permitted. Any ideas how to work around / correct way of this?

```
<camel:camelContext id="myCamelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <propertyPlaceholder id="korek_config" location="file:${config.path}/my-config.properties"/>

    <route>

        <from uri="...."/>

        <multicast parallelProcessing="true"
                   strategyRef="balancesAggregator"
                   timeout="{{retrieve.balances.timeout}}">

            <to uri="direct:balancesRead"/>
            <bean ref="serviceBean" method="getBalances"/>
        </multicast>

    </route>    

</camel:camelContext>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using integer properties this way, check out http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html in the section "Using property placeholders for any kind of attribute in the XML DSL.". You will need to define a namespace for the properties in your blueprint/spring definition:

```
xmlns:prop="http://camel.apache.org/schema/placeholder"
```

then you should be able to refer to the property with

```
<multicast parallelProcessing="true"  prop:timeout="retrieve.balances.timeout">
```